# Working with multiple categories

Tags: categories, relations, category

Does anyone know if you can work with `releatedTo` between categories? I’d like to get all the categories in a `categories.group`s that are related to a single category

I have some entries in a channel, lets call it `parts`. The `parts` have two categories from two separate groups.

- Group 1 is `partType` which has the categories `engine` `interior` and `transmission`
- Group 2 is `manufacturer` which has the categories `ford` and `chrysler`.

On the category-page for `ford`, i’d like to list all the `parts` in the `ford` category, grouped by `partType`

But I don’t wand to show the `partType` categories that have no `parts` by the current `manufacturer`

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out!

If anyone is stuck at the same place here’s my solution:

```
{# category is 'ford' #}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('support').relatedTo(category).find() %}
{% set partsCategories = craft.categories.group('partsGroup').relatedTo(entries) %}

{# Partslist #}
{% for partsCategory in partsCategories %}

    {{partsCategory.title}}
    {% for part in craft.entries.relatedTo([
      'and',
      { targetElement: partsCategory },
      { targetElement: category }
    ]) %}

      {{part.title}}

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```